# Spring STS : how to know the right URL (http://localhost:8080/...) to use a demo appli?

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, localhost

I'm beginning with Spring, so I downloaded some applications from https://github.com/
I try to test them on my navigator : `localhost:8080/(application-name)` but for the most of them it does not work ("the resource is not available").
- For example : I install "spring-hibernate-cf" => localhost:8080/spring-hibernate-cf does not work
- I install "spring-petclinic" => `localhost:8080/spring-petclinic` does not work => but `localhost:8080/petclinic` is OK !
So how to know the correct url for each demo application ?

Comment: Thank you Sotirios, I finally found the solution : I found the "context-root" value in \.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component of my \workspace\project

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Tomcat as your `Servlet` container, there is configuration file called `server.xml`. Inside it you will have a `<Host>` element that should contain a `<Context` element for each of your web applications. If it doesn't exist, then Tomcat is using the name of your web application's directory (in `/webapps`) as the context path.

This is explained in further detail in the [Tomcat 7 context documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution :
in my `(workspace)\(project)\.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file
the name is set in `<property name="context-root" value="..."/>`